# Оптимизация скорости работы БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Всем привет, есть таблица `translate` на базе `mysql` с переводом в размере 700 тыс записей, делаю в цикле перевод каждое слово:

```
foreach($res->data->skuModel as $skuModel){
    getTranslate($skuModel->propName);
}
```

при каждом цикле идет запрос к базе:

```
function getTranslate($text) {
   $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `translate` WHERE zh='$text' LIMIT 1");
   foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
     return $result['translate'];
   }
}
```

И вот такой грязный код тормозить страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выполнения за 5 секунд это еще нормально. Если пройтись по циклу 100 раз то вот тогда начинается ад. Не правильный подход написания кода не реально тормозить страницу вообще страница должна сгенерироваться за 0,5 сек но тут у меня такой кошмар даже не знаю что мне делать.

Вопрос:
Как мне оптимизировать код.

Comment: Не понял эту фразу: `есть таблица на базе с переводом в размере 30 тыс столбца делаю в цикле перевод каждое слово`. Можете переформулировать вопрос?

Comment: по полю zh в таблице индекс есть ? Если нет - сделайте. Если не поможет - приведите план выполнения запроса (`explain`), без него оптимизация чего либо связанного с MySQL невозможна

Comment: Да конечно есть индекс: https://pp.userapi.com/c841324/v841324678/19050/zlmw7Urza9E.jpg я ведь показывал как делаю запрос к базе. `explain` это синтаксис `mysql`? как я могу действовать в маем случае, и это работает?

Comment: И где на этой картинке видно, что "конечно есть индекс"? почему названия полей на картинке не соответствуют коду в вопросе?

Comment: @Ипатьев тогда я не понял что такое индекс, как сделать тогда индекса?

Comment: набери в адресной строке своего браузера слова "база данных индекс" и открой для себя огромный новый мир

Comment: а код твой здесь не при чем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена как сказали `@mike` и `@Ипатьев` использовал `индекс` заменил тип из `text` на `varchar(1000)` подключил `индекс` и вуаля в 100 000 раз быстрее.